# SQL Where Condition with IF Statement

Tags: sql, if-statement, where-clause

So I'm trying to write a query to pull some data and I have one condition that needs to be met and I can't seem to figure out how to actually execute it. What I'm trying to achieve is that if a column is not null in one table, then I want to check another table and see if there is a specific value in one those columns. So in a psuedo code type of way I'm trying to do this

```
SELECT id, user_name, created_date, transaction_number
FROM TableA
WHERE (IF TableA.response_id IS NULL OR
IF (SELECT type_id from TableB WHERE (type_id NOT IN ('4)) AND (id = TableA.response_id))
```

So from here what I'm trying to do is pull all transactions for customers that have no responses in them, but from those that do have responses I still want to grab transaction that's don't have a specific code associated to them. I'm not sure if it's possible to do it in this manner or if I need to create some temporary tables that can then be manipulated but I'm stuck on this one condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first I thought you wanted the `CASE` statement from the wording of your question, but I think you're just looking for an `OUTER JOIN` with an `OR` statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.id, a.user_name, a.created_date, a.transaction_number
FROM TableA A
    LEFT JOIN TableB B ON A.response_id = B.Id
WHERE A.response_id IS NULL 
    OR B.type_id NOT IN (4)
```

- [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: Although this didn't really work for me, it did help lead to the right answer so I'm marking this as the answer since it should work for almost every other scenario

Answer (score 0):

where TableA.Response_id is null or (select count(1) from TableB WHERE (type_id NOT IN ('4)) AND (id = TableA.response_id)) = 0

provided that your subquery is logically correct.

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm not 100% certain I follow, but assuming what you want is to see if there are response entries for a particular ID in Table A I think you want something like this.

```
SELECT a.id, user_name, created_date, transaction_number
FROM TableA a
LEFT JOIN TableB b
ON a.id=b.id
LEFT JOIN TableC c
ON a.id=c.id
WHERE isnull(b.id,c.id) IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY a.id, user_name, created_date, transaction_number
```

ISNULL will return b.id if it is not null, c.id if c.id is not null and NULL otherwise.  That will tell you if there's a response for a.id in either TableB or TableC.  That's assuming TableB & TableC are more like logs.  If you're saying those table will certainly have an entry for a.id then it's just a matter of replacing b.id & c.id with b.[response_column] & c.[response_column] respectively.